# Json array to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have an JSON array from laravel like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5a15e52b5bd98b7a0040fac8
                        )

                    [UnitPrice] => 18
                    [UnitsInStock] => 39
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5a15e52b5bd98b7a0040fac9
                        )

                    [UnitPrice] => 19
                    [UnitsInStock] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5a15e52b5bd98b7a0040faca
                        )

                    [UnitPrice] => 10
                    [UnitsInStock] => 13
                )

        )

)
```

How can I take only the `UnitPrice` and the `UnitsInStock` as an array? Is there any way without using a loop?

I want to use it like this:

```
...

->dataset('UnitPrice', [5,20,100,...]) // array's values = [5,20,100,...]

->dataset('UnitsInStock', [52,120,100,...]) // array's values = [52,120,100,...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a [lists](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_lists) method to get array for a given column. Otherwise, you can use the [array_column](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-column.php) method of PHP.

```
$unitPrices = array_column($items, 'UnitPrice');
```